# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings' Not able to fit KNNBasic Model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I am trying to create a baseline model: KNNBasic with Cosine Similarity (user-based). I have done a train test split. I will be as detailed here as possible.

Ratings Data Preprocessing:

```
sample_clean = sample.drop('Time', axis=1) #dropping time stamp
class MyDataset(dataset.DatasetAutoFolds):
     #this function creates a surprise friendly dataset
     #this function already has folds built into it for cross-validation
     self.raw_sample = [(uid, pid, r, None) for (uid, pid, r) in zip(sample_clean['UserId'], sample_clean['ProductId'], sample_clean['Score'])]
     self.reader = reader
```

I then intanstiate my reader

```
reader = Reader(line_format = 'user item rating', rating_scale=(0,5))
```

I then parse my sample_clean dataframe into a surprise friendly dataset

```
surprise_sample = MyDataset(sample_clean, reader)
```

I check the format:

```
type(surprise_sample)
```

I get an output of

```
_main_.MyDataset
```

I proceed to make a column of raw_ratings and extract it from sample_clean:

```
raw_ratings = sample_clean.Score
```

Next, I perform a train validation split which works fine.

```
#test data
test_threshold = int(.85*len(sample_clean)
train_sample = sample_clean[:test_threshold]
test_raw_sample = sample_clean[test_thresholds:]
```

#train data

```
train_threshold = int(.8*len(train_sample))
validation_raw_sample = train_sample[train_threshold:]
train_raw_sample = train_sample[:train_threshold]
```

I then check to see that no data been lost during my train test split:

```
len(train_raw_sample) + len(test_raw_sample) + len(validation_raw_sample)
#output is 5000 which is what I wanted
```

I HAVE TROUBLE BELOW, I am building a baseline model that is KNNBasic with Cosine Similarity (user-based)

```
#cosine similarity
sim_cos = {'name': 'cosine', 'user_based': True}
#instantiate reader
basic_user = knns.KNNBasic(sim_options = sim_cos)
#fit the model 
simcos_crossval_user = cross_validate(basic_user, sample_clean, measures=['rmse', 'mae'], cv=3, return_train_measure=True, n_jobs=-1, verbose=True)
```

this last line of code doesn't seem to work, I get an output error of:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'
```

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative you can try for parsing custom dataframe into surprise friendly dataset:

```
reader = Reader(line_format = 'user item rating', rating_scale=(0,5))
```

The columns must correspond to user id, item id and ratings (in that order):

```
data = Dataset.load_from_df(sample_clean [['userId', 'productId', 'Score']], reader)
```

You can find more details [here.](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#load-dom-dataframe-py)